# What is a raw database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got a request as "This data will be only be in this format in  the RAW database." But I'm not sure what is the RAW database. They wanted to consolidate our data and asked us prepare raw database. How to make the raw database from SQL Server 2008 R2?

Oops, it could make some confusion like these comments, but unfortunately, that is all information I got about the request. So probably, I need to change the question. Then what is the appropriate to ask them for clarification? In addition, it's not a database name. I need to prepare a kind of file to transfer it to HQ to create a bigger database. I thought there might be a file type called raw in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: *WHERE* in what *CONTEXT* did you get that message?

Comment: Give us context. Ask them what they meant by "RAW database." The client making the request will probably know what they meant by "RAW database" better than we ever will. Maybe they mean xml, csv, or any other number of formats. We can't read their minds.

Comment: Might be an acronym? [Read and Write](http://www.acronymfinder.com/RAW.html) as opposed to read only?

Comment: Perhaps is a database named `[RAW]`...

Comment: One interpretation could be: a RAW database is a database consisting of raw data files, probably like [NoDB](http://stratos.seas.harvard.edu/publications/nodb-efficient-query-execution-raw-data-files-0
).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm that sounds almost like a quote from some fancy database book using "raw database" as a new buzzword.

A database is at its best, when it contains "raw data" (only the pure data, no statistics, averages calculated -> normalized database).

In some cases you can not have raw data and need to keep track of calculated values in your database (mostly for performance reasons to fasten up query times) and I could imagine that those guys just want you to throw those out to have a "raw database" constisting of only "raw data".